# GeoDjango PointField admin visualization

Tags: django-admin, geodjango

I was wondering how I could change the default PointField visualization (the Openstreetmap) in admin so that I could enter simple latitude/longitude instead of select a point on the map?

I looked at this one [Latitude/longitude widget for pointfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021852/latitude-longitude-widget-for-pointfield) but could not get it working in any way in Django 1.6b4

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

As Bibhas says you can override the widget used for the field, but the simple text input may not be usefull. So here is an example with a full widget that can be used for PointField of geodjango:

```
class LatLongWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    """
    A Widget that splits Point input into latitude/longitude text inputs.
    """

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None):
        widgets = (forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
                   forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs))
        super(LatLongWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return tuple(value.coords)
        return (None, None)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        mylat = data[name + '_0']
        mylong = data[name + '_1']

        try:
            point = Point(float(mylat), float(mylong))
        except ValueError:
            return ''

        return point
```

And now you can override your model Admin:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'approval', 'company_view',)
    list_filter = ('approval',)
    formfield_overrides = {
        geomodels.PointField: {'widget': LatLongWidget},
    }
```

Comment: This reverses them on each save, I think the reversed should be removed in decompress.

Answer (score 2):

You can override a widget with another in Django admin. [From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

# Import our custom widget and our model from where they're defined
from myapp.widgets import RichTextEditorWidget
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': RichTextEditorWidget},
    }
```

This overrides `TextField` with `RichTextEditorWidget`. Just find the field type for point field and override it with TextField.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are new to gis, and you don't know where point is defined, the LatLongWidget above needs to know what Point is. You can import it like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos.point import Point
```

Answer (score 0):

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22309195/2996101) I approach this issue by using two extra "Decimal Fields" in the `ModelForm`. This way, the `Latitude` and `Longitude` fields appear in the admin for the user's convenience without affecting the database, whatsoever.

They always reflect the relevant values if a `PointField` exists while they can update them or create them if the `PointField` does not exist.