# Geodjango admin, display pointfield not as map

Tags: django, admin, point, geodjango

This may be a stupid question but I can't find any clear answers.

How do I change the display in the Django Admin so the Pointfield does not show up like a OpenLayer Map but as a regular input field. I need to see the long, lat for debugging..

Do i have to change the field type? Widgets?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [GeoDjango PointField admin visualization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231109/geodjango-pointfield-admin-visualization)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

This is how I managed -at last- to keep separate fields for lattitude and longitude without having to save them in the database since the values are already saved in the PointField.

The idea is :

- If we are inserting a new entry, the latitude and longitude fields will be used to set the PointField
- If we open an existing PointField entry, it will be used to provide the latitude and longitude values in the relevant FormFields.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels


class Entry(geomodels.Model):
    point = geomodels.PointField(
        srid=4326,
        blank=True,
        )
```

admin.py

```
from myapp.forms import EntryForm
from django.contrib import admin


class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EntryForm


admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Entry
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point


class MarketEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    latitude = forms.FloatField(
        min_value=-90,
        max_value=90,
        required=True,
    )
    longitude = forms.FloatField(
        min_value=-180,
        max_value=180,
        required=True,
    )

    class Meta(object):
        model = MarketEntry
        exclude = []
        widgets = {'point': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        coordinates = self.initial.get('point', None)
        if isinstance(coordinates, Point):
            self.initial['longitude'], self.initial['latitude'] = coordinates.tuple

    def clean(self):
        data = super().clean()
        latitude = data.get('latitude')
        longitude = data.get('longitude')
        point = data.get('point')
        if latitude and longitude and not point:
            data['point'] = Point(longitude, latitude)
        return data
```

---

From the [source code of PointField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py#L297) we see that its [form class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py#L109) uses the [OpenLayersWidget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py#L18) which [inherits](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/forms/widgets.py#L81) from the [BaseGeometryWidget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/forms/widgets.py#L16).

The conclusion is that in this class, the variable [display_raw](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/forms/widgets.py#L25) is by default set to `False`.

If you set it to `True` in `yourapp/admin.py`, you will get a textbox with lat and long and other data, useful for debugging purposes:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from yourapp.models import YourClass
from django.contrib.gis import forms
from django.contrib.gis.db import models    


class YourClassAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    your_attribute = forms.PointField(widget=forms.OSMWidget(attrs={
            'display_raw': True}))

class YourClassAdmin(admin.GeoModelAdmin):
    form = YourClassAdminForm


admin.site.register(YourClass, YourClassAdmin)
```

---

[There is also a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22309195/2996101) to have both a map and manual insertion of longitude / latitude permanently (not only for debugging).

The idea is to use FloatFields to insert the Longitude/Latitude and update the PointField with the inserted data.

Answer (score 2):

You can override a widget with another in Django admin. [From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

# Import our custom widget and our model from where they're defined
from myapp.widgets import RichTextEditorWidget
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': RichTextEditorWidget},
    }
```

This overrides `TextField` with `RichTextEditorWidget`. Just find the field type for point field and override it with TextField.