# How do I add PointField in django-admin?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, geodjango

I can't seem to add a value in django-admin for `PointFied`.
I am still new in django-admin so I don't really know what I'm missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Django Admin can't add a PointField]

[image]

I am using Django 2.2.2 and python 3.x

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408638/geodjango-admin-display-pointfield-not-as-map

Comment: @DharanidharReddy thank you so much. Got the idea of using widgets from other answers in this post.